# Virtualization implement in Amazon cloud computing

Tags: amazon-web-services, scalability, virtualization

I am a beginner in cloud computing and have read some documents about cloud computing in Amazon. I have a question about Xen and the art of virtualization implemented in Amazon web service. As we know cloud computing offers elasticity and scalablity for deploying applications. When we deploy a cloud app to Amazon, by the time the number of users of our app has been increased and I think Amazon will automatically generate a new virtual server to handle user request. At the first time, the cloud app runs on one virtual server and now it runs on two virtual servers.

Does anyone know how an application can run on two virtual servers on Amazon? How it synchronizes data, use of CPU resources,...?

Is there any document from Amazon point out this problem and virtualization implemention?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you create an instance on the Amazon EC2, they create a new virtual server(called as instance) for you to use it. They do not scale the number of instances based on the user requests. It is upto the user to create the instances for use.

The following [link](http://www.aosabook.org/en/distsys.html) has an exhaustive explanation about how the distributed and scalable applications work